# Design -- Parsing and reducing filenames tokens

Tags: python, token

I'm facing a problem where I would need to parse filenames where I don't know the patterns of said filenames and be able to group them by common patterns (/ denominators?)

*No need to worry about file extensions*

Assuming the following names :

> Paraguay-2018_500x500
>
> Paraguay-2018_120X120
>
> Paraguay-2018_64xx64
>
> Matt-21_Birthday_2019
>
> Matt-21_Birthday-1024x800_2019
>
> Matt-21_Birthday-800x800_2019
>
> Matt-21_Birthday-500x500_2019

You'd get the following result :

> [["Paraguay","2018"],
> ["Matt","21","Birthday","2019"]]

**As you can see, the pattern to remove is a set of dimensions, and I could get away with building a regex and hoping for the best.
But I'm interested in trying to avoid regex for the usual reasons.**

It is quite obvious from the examples provided but I'm going to list below the constraints of the environment :

- Filenames don't follow a predefined pattern / naming convention (see how - and _ are used)
- The pattern to remove isn't regular either (consider the xx typo)
- Throwing out numbers isn't an option
- Said numbers do not follow a pattern either (21, 2018, 2019)

I've looked into NLTK's doc to see if my problem would be a good fit but most examples I have seen have been for classic text rather than filenames.

While code would be great, I'm perfectly happy with a handful of pointers to get started / being put on the right path. This isn't homework outsourcing :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` with a pattern that looks for either purely alphabets or purely digits, and uses negative lookbehind and negative lookahead patterns to avoid them mixing together:

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?<![a-z\d])(?:[a-z]+|\d+)(?![a-z\d])', s, re.IGNORECASE) for s in l]
```

so that given:

```
l = [
    'Paraguay-2018_500x500',
    'Paraguay-2018_120X120',
    'Paraguay-2018_64xx64',
    'Matt-21_Birthday_2019',
    'Matt-21_Birthday-1024x800_2019',
    'Matt-21_Birthday-800x800_2019',
    'Matt-21_Birthday-500x500_2019'
]
```

this returns:

```
[['Paraguay', '2018'],
 ['Paraguay', '2018'],
 ['Paraguay', '2018'],
 ['Matt', '21', 'Birthday', '2019'],
 ['Matt', '21', 'Birthday', '2019'],
 ['Matt', '21', 'Birthday', '2019'],
 ['Matt', '21', 'Birthday', '2019']]
```

If you don't want to use regex, however, you can instead use `itertools.groupby` with a key function of `str.isalnum` to obtain alphanumeric tokens from a given string, and then use another filter that combines `str.isalpha` and `str.isdigit` to exclude tokens that are a mix of alphabets and digits:

```
from itertools import groupby
[[t for t in (''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(s, key=str.isalnum) if k) if t.isalpha() or t.isdigit()] for s in l]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for giving it a shot @blhsing but I explicitly said I wanted to try and avoid regex as much as possible.

Have edited my question to highlight that.

Thanks for spending some time though

Comment: Why do you not want regex if it's  one that actually gets you what you want?

Comment: @Valentin: Indeed, what exactly are the "usual reasons" to avoid regex? I ask because they seem like a very suitable tool for this problem.

Comment: @ValentinPalussière I've updated my answer with a solution that does not use regex then.